# vue does not recover from me specifying a non existing location for v-model

Tags: vue.js

When I have a textarea like

```
<textarea v-model="foo.abc.text"></textarea>
```

and either `foo` or `foo.abc` does not exist yet then
vue removes either parts of the DOM or is giving me a blank page.

It does never recover.

That alone is annoying, regardless of if I am using a debug version of vue or not.

If I try to use an approach that I have been advised to use earlier like

```
<textarea v-model="foo?.abc?.text"></textarea>
```

then I am still out of luck, I presume that I get a "rvalue" using those question marks and what I need rather is a variable location.

How do I, with as little trickery as possible, allow `v-model` to exist later on even if it doesnt exist now (late binding)?

Comment: You don't want undefined behavior before `foo.abc.text` becomes available. I would suggest `value` + `@input` or show textarea conditionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shape your data accordingly and initialize it with empty values:

```js
data(){
  return {
    foo: {
      abc: {
        text: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can later populate it e.g. with the result of api call, but it's still better to initialize data properly

Comment: A lot of work! Yes, I have been forced into this in some cases. I respect the strictness some people have, but some wants to use more relaxed approaches.

Comment: If you're using Vue 2 then it's better to do it this way because you won't face reactivity caveats then

Comment: What would those reactivity caveats consist of?

Comment: For example Vue can't detect changes in objects that were not initialized inside data option at component creation. You can read more here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going the `:value` + `@input` way. It allow more control over the  input model, and does not require hiding it.

```
<textarea :value="!!foo && foo.abc.text" @input="(val) => !!foo && (foo.abc.text = val)" />
```

You can even hook in a validator:

```
<textarea 
    :value="!!foo && foo.abc.text" 
    @input="(val) => !!foo && (foo.abc.text = val)" 
    :rules="v => !v && 'The object has not been initialised'"
/>
```

Comment: Thats trickery, but maybe good one...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I can live with and then I got a comment in the same direction:

Conditionally showing the textarea.

`v-if` seems to do it but it falls under the "trickery" category, I think (angularjs would be more relaxed).

```
<textarea v-if="foo!=null" v-model="foo.abc"></textarea>
```

The symptom to hiding components if something is not all correct is not the best part of vue.js. Better show them and color them red.